How to avoid generating .d.ts.map files when using tsc to generate only declaration files?
I am creating a build with tsup. However, dts option throws many errors. And I also see that in the official tsup documentation it says that typescript declarations generated by any tool other than tsc are not guarenteed to be perfect.
Thus, I am using tsc for type declarations.
I am building my app like this
tsup && tsc -p custom-config.json

// custom-config.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    "sourceMap": false,
    ...
  }
}

I want to to avoid generating .d.ts.map.

While searching for answers, I landed up on the official typescript docs.
I found an option called declarationMap - https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#declarationMap
Replacing sourceMap in the config file with declarationMap: false fixed the issue.
// custom-config.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    "declarationMap": false,
    ...
  }
}

